# Dropbox image url changed

Tags: image, url

i use to create image url using dropbox and it used to work in saas software called commission gorilla.
But recently the image url from dropbox has changed and it more lengthy that the previous one and it do not work in commision gorilla and it says the image url is invalid .

WORKING URL/OLD URL-https://www.dropbox.com/s/ch2c48t2z1ehoyc/Bloxi_AI-removebg-preview.png?dl=0

Not working /new url- https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oayou9l6noezq3u7d3rn/Ai_crew-removebg-preview.png?dl=0

i have tried editing the new url same as the old one but didnt worked out . Need help in order to get this resolved